# Pointing subdirectory of a domain to another website at another server

Tags: dns, hosting

- There is domain `www.example.com` which has its DNS managed through Cloudflare.
- The website of this domain is hosted at `host A`.
- In the server of another host `host B` there is a directory with the files of a project's website which currently has no domain pointing to it, and thus the site is currently inaccessible.
- I want to point a sub-directory of the domain `www.example.com/projectsite` to the project website at `host B`.

How can this be done? As far as I can understand it can't be done through DNS. I have nameservers and IP address of `host B`. Keep in mind that the site of the actual domain is at another host `host A`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no there is not.

If you have access to host A, you can configure the web server software (Nginx, Apache, or whatever) to proxy the request to another server.